# How to have a script check for admin privileges', and rerun itself as admin if it doesn't

Tags: powershell, permissions

So I am trying to create a solution for an issue I am having in powershell.

I need to come up with a way to have my script check if it was ran with Administrative Rights. If it wasn't it needs to rerun itself with admin rights.

My situation is special from the other times this has been asked (From all the posts I have checked) as our normal user accounts doesn't have the rights, so I need to enter alternative credentials.

If this helps, Our Administrative Accounts do have an ending identifier in the name if we can filter off this. EX. "John.Doe.A" and the .A indicates this is an Admin account.

Comment: There are lots of examples of auto-elevation scripts all over the web. SO rules:  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Continuing from my comment.***

Your case is not unique. It gets asked a lot here and in many other spots.

['powershell SecretManagement module' auto elevate](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20SecretManagement%20module%27%20auto%20elevate&t=h_&ia=web)

> Sample hit:
>
> https://petri.com/powershell-secrets-management-how-to-securely-elevate-privileges-in-powershell-scripts

You store needed credentials in the 'Windows Credential Manager', and call from the as needed. MS even provides a new Secrets Module for this kind of use case. See more details via MS Docs on the topic.

Like this:

> SecretManagement and SecretStore are Generally Available
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available

and this:

> Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules

```
Get-Secret
Get-SecretInfo
Get-SecretVault
Register-SecretVault
Remove-Secret
Set-Secret
Set-SecretInfo
Set-SecretVaultDefault
Test-SecretVault
Unregister-SecretVault
```

Comment: led me down the right path, it led me to doublecheck into Powershell credentials manager, I didn't look into it before now because it didn't work in a separate use case and ended up leading me to this page "https://blog.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html"

After some slight modification of how it checks for admin rights (I just did a match for our admin identifier instead of checking if I had the admin group) it worked right out of the gate!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$adminrole = ([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
$wid = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
If (-not $wid.IsInRole($adminrole)) {        
    $newProcess = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo "PowerShell"
    $newProcess.Arguments = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    $newProcess.Verb = "runas";
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newProcess);
    exit
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).